# Tips to sum values and ignore all filter but the fields of two table in Dax?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have 3 dimensions tables and one fact Table  Sales

- DimCalendar (Fields Year/Month/Day/Week)
- DimCountry  (Field : CountryName)
- DimManager  (Field ManagerName)
- FctSales    (Field : Amount)

I want to create a measure to Sum the Amount of the Sales (FctSales) and filter only to the fields of the tables DimCalendar and DimCountry.

After research, i was thinking about the function AllExcept, like :

> CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Amt]);ALLExcept(Sales;Country[Country];Calendar[Year]...)

but if i do that, i will have to write every columns of the table Calendar and Table Country in the AllExcept, i am wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: Is `Offer` your sales fact table?

Comment: Is your goal is to remove filters related to `DimManager`?

Comment: @AlexisOlson : The Sales is my fact table.

It's not just to remove the filters related to DimManager, it's more : 
than i don't want any filter but the DimCountry/DimCalendar. 
(I will add more tables in the project and i want to filter only in the table DimCountry and DimCalendar only to this measure).

Comment: You refer to `Offer` in your code but not `FctSales`. How are these related?

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake, I just edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using `REMOVEFILTERS()` to remove every filter and then put back the filters over `DimCountry` and `DimCalendar` might work?

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Sales[Amt] );
    REMOVEFILTERS ();
    VALUES( DimCountry[CountryName] );
    VALUES( DimCalendar[Date] )
)
```

`DimCalendar[Date]` should be the column used for the relationship with Sales.
This measure first evaluates the filter arguments in the current filter context.

Using as filter the columns used for the relationships guarantees that whatever the column used for filtering this would be mapped over the relationship.

Then, the `REMOVEFILTERS()` will remove any existing context filter and eventually the filter arguments evaluated during the first step will be applied, putting back any filtering that was set over `DimCalendar` and `DimCountry`.

Comment: Thank you for your tips :) 

I have try another solution with the VALUES too :
CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Amt]);ALL(Sales);VALUES(Country);VALUES(Calendar)

Comment: Great solution, thanks!